# Borderless printing in Microsoft Excel 2016 not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, printing, margins

As a quick note, I feel silly to ask such an obvious question: I cannot make Microsoft Excel 2016 print without any margins!

**What I would like to do:**

I would like to color the left top of my document with a height of 1 inch. There must not be any margin on the final document (printed or saved as PDF) or it would look ugly.

**What I have tried:**

- I set `Page Layout`, `Margins` to 0 (top, left, right, bottom, header, footer).
- I went to `Print` and tried setting `Printer Properties` to borderless.

**What actually happens:**

See the image below what happens in the left top corner of the document in printing preview (and also when I actually print it or save as PDF:

[image: example]

**What I have found out:**

If a cell has no border, it still uses up some space. But if I put a thick border to the left top cell, the upper margin magically disappears. But on the left of the document, there still remains a very small white margin.

**What else?**

I honestly don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert an image in the top left of the size you require and place it so that it covers the margins.